# How to install multi website on VPS with LEMP and CentOS?

Tags: nginx, centos, vps

My question is like title: How to install multi website on VPS with LEMP and CentOS?

I created VPS on Digitalocean, and now I want to create LEMP via the command line.
So, how I begin step by step with the right way?

Comment: This is a question best asked on Server Fault -- Stack Overflow is meant for code specific issues ..

Comment: Yep, thank for your remind Zak!

Comment: Thank you all, I research and found this article in Vietnamese language and it answer well my question -> http://www.wpviet.info/cai-dat-cau-hinh-lemp-chay-nhieu-site-tren-cung-1-vps-voi-hocvps/